# NSURLSession convert image during uploading

Tags: ios, nsurlrequest, nsurlrequestcachepolicy

I am uploading an image to my server, and meantime JPG image get converted, and converted image will not anymore readable.

Tried to set HTTP "`Cache-Control`", but no effect it has.

Any idea how to prevent conversion?

```
let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: "xxx")!
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
request.setValue("private, no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, no-transform, max-age=0", forHTTPHeaderField: "Cache-Control")
request.HTTPBody = NSData(contentsOfFile: path)

let configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
NSURLSession(configuration: configuration).dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, urlRequest, error in }).resume()
```

Attached the look of the before and after image data.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by JPG image converted? Are you saying that the file uploaded at the server gets converted to some different format?

Comment: Right, attached image about it.

Comment: no `Content-type` value in the header? poor server...! it seems you expect the server being a mind-reader or something.

Comment: I want just save the raw data, without understanding the semantics. FYI I tried with `Content-type`: `image/jpeg` and also does not work.

Comment: I think saving the raw data is creating the problem for you. Why don't you try to upload the files using the method: `uploadTaskWithRequest: fromFile`

Comment: Tried `uploadTaskWithRequest: fromFile` also, has same effect.

Comment: @János, it is not about you, it is about the server. it must know about whether the data is binary otherwise some characters might be updated by the actual system's current character encoder; in case of binary file you cannot allow that happen, which may lead you to need encoding and decoding the binary data, using like _base64_ or _ascii7_ or something as well, whichever your server-side supports and expects.

Comment: I agree with @holex. You should check the server side code.

Comment: Right problem was server side issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37486019/why-node-js-convert-post-body