# Why node.js convert POST body?

Tags: node.js, openshift

Want to save JPG binary body data to file system in `OpenShift`. But somehow received info will get converted. Do you have any idea why? Is it possible that node.js treat data as text and does an encoding / decoding on it?

```
var myServer = http.createServer(function(request, response)
{
    var data = '';

    request.on('data', function (chunk){
        data += chunk;
    });

    request.on('end',function(){

    var date = new Date();
    var url_parts = url.parse(request.url,true);

    if(url_parts.pathname == '/setImage') {

        if(data != null && data.length > 0) {

            fs.writeFile('/var/lib/openshift/555dd1415973ca1660000085/app-root/data/asset/' + url_parts.query.filename, data, 'binary', function(err) {
                if (err) throw err
                console.log(date + ' File saved. ' + url_parts.query.filename  + ' ' + data.length)

                response.writeHead(200)
                response.end()
            })
        }
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are initializing `data` with a string, so adding `chunk`'s with `+=` to it will convert the chunks to string as well (which is subject to character encoding).

Instead, you should collect the chunks as an array of `Buffer`'s and use [`Buffer.concat()`](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_class_method_buffer_concat_list_totallength) to create the final Buffer:

```
var chunks = [];

request.on('data', function (chunk){
    chunks.push(chunk);
});

request.on('end', function() {
  var data = Buffer.concat(chunks);
  ...
});
```

Comment: Saved my life, I was struggling with it since days. Thanks!